# why ngrok does not display css in html webpage?

Tags: python, flask, google-colaboratory, ngrok, pyngrok

[code and directory structure for files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFRZq.png)

The loaded webpage does not reflect styles.css on public url, this works fine for me localhost. I am running it on google-colab and trying to make a flask web app on it. how can i make index.html reflect the stylesheet?

I tried changing directories, and putting it in a 'static' directory in same folder as 'template' and changes stylesheet path to "../static/styles.css" still it did not work.

code :

```
from flask.templating import render_template
from flask import Flask
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok
template_f = '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/MyApp/template'
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=template_f)
run_with_ngrok(app)
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
a = app.run()
```

Comment: Please post the code as text not screenshot.